Get with python address for default folder of MS Edge-browser for downloading files
Let's assume that the default folder for downloading files is set in the Microsoft Edge browser E:\Edge_downloads
Is it possible in Python to get information about the address of this folder?
I tried looking in the registry, but it's not there.

If you changed Edge download folder, it will show in Edge Preference file. You can find the file like below:

Open edge://version/ in Edge.
Find Profile path and open that folder.
The Preference file is in that folder.



Open Preference file and search default_directory in download string like below. Here I set Edge download folder to E:\download and you can see it's the value of default_directory:

"download":{"default_directory":"E:\\download",...

You can try to use Python to search in this Preference file to get the path of Edge download folder.

Nice answer. FYI. In my system(Unix) it is in savefile key(not in download)

Yes. I test in Windows, and it's in both download and savefile keys if using Windows.

I found that there are also such cases: "savefile":{"default_directory":"E:\download",...
